# List operations using Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm making a simple mean stack app with Angular 5.
I know my code is not that performant and don't use best practices.
This code is my Typescript file for a product list. I only want my products to show where the field 'user' in the collection products is equal to the loggedinUser.

At the moment it's showing all my products no matter which user is logged in. I don't work with models or Mongoose.

The for loop doesn't work. It's says that 'this.products' is empty.
Can someone explain to me why it is empty and how I can solve this issue?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

// Import the DataService
import { DataService } from '../../data.service';
import { UserService } from '../../user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {
  products: Array<any>;
  productsCU : Array<any>;
  ngOnInit() {
  }

  constructor(private _dataService: DataService , private userService: UserService) { 
        this._dataService.getInventory()
        .subscribe(res => this.products = res);


         for(var i = 0;i < this.products.length;i++){
                    if(this.products[i].user== userService.getNameUserLoggedIn()){
                        this.productsCU.push(this.products[i]);
                    }
                }

  }
```

Comment: did you console log the products , what does yyour template look like

Comment: Your title kind of sucks for someone trying to help, please rewrite it for a specific problem.

Comment: how should you name it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, if there is a data problem with the console.log then its to do with ur services getInventoy() function and where ever that gets the data from.

```
this._dataService.getInventory().subscribe((res) => {
   this.products = res;
   console.log(this.products);

   for()...

});
```

I don't reccomend the approach you are doing here to get ALL products then filter by ID. As you've mentioned its not "performant". You should query that specifically in your backend to get products where user id is "123".

Having said that a array.filter seems appropriate use case here instead of a long winded for loop.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
let userProducts = this.products.filter(p => p.user == userService.getNameUserLoggedIn())
```

where "p" is each product within this.products Array

Comment: probably wrong use of how to add an object in an array

Comment: Just make sure your this.products[i] is an object. Should be fine

Comment: Fyi, if you are looking for best practise, it makes more sense to query your backend to get all products where user is id 123. Rather than getting all products and then filtering in frontend, but thats for another question. :)

Comment: yeah I guess that's a better way to do it, thanks for the advice, i'll look into it !